# How to save data of a file to a variable forever without reading it again anytime we need to open in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file named option.plist, its data is very long. I'm trying to write a program in python to compare the data of option.plist with user's input file's data.

```
arg = input("Drag & drop your file here: ")
with open("option.plist",'rb') as f:
   data = f.read()
with open(arg,'rb') as f1:
   user_data = f1.read()
if data == user_data:
   print("Valid ticket")
else:
   print("Invalid ticket")
   return -1
```

However, with this code, I'll always have to bring option.plist with this program to anywhere, in order to read its data. So my question is: Is there anyway to save data of option.plist forever to a variable? Remember there are lots of line breaks in option.plist. Thanks in advance

Comment: please give this question an upvote if you feel interesting